# Insert rows into random places in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a very large sample dataframe (~640,000 rows), and I'm currently testing to see if a parser I've built can detect specific phrases. This dataframe is full of text strings.

I'm trying to find a way to insert a specific number of rows into random places within the dataframe.

This the basic structure of the dataframe:

```
                                            Comments            code  
0  The stupidity of it is that gamed to total def...            NaN  
1  called poker face she s actually...                          WP  
2  Example not identifying the fundamental scarci...            NaN  
3  No tol is bait That s the point...                           NaN
```

The imputed rows have the same structure as the rows in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following was the structure of your input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Comments':['Text1','Text2','Text3','Text4'], 'code':['WP', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
newrow = pd.DataFrame({"Comments":'Text_new', 'code':np.nan}, index=[0])
```

The Initial Dataframe:

```
  Comments code
0    Text1   WP
1    Text2  NaN
2    Text3  NaN
3    Text4  NaN
```

The new row to be added:

```
   Comments  code
0  Text_new   NaN
```

You can use this line of code to add the new row into a random location in the dataframe

```
from numpy.random import randint
random_row = randint(len(df)+1)

df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:random_row], newrow, df.iloc[random_row:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   Comments code
0     Text1   WP
1     Text2  NaN
2     Text3  NaN
3  Text_new  NaN
4     Text4  NaN
```